# Javascript array function parameter passing

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I was watching a javascript tutorial and I don't understand some syntax. He was teaching enhanced object properties and I don't understand the next two things:
You can see that he created a variable (pricePropName with the value "PRICE". Why he set the value price and why is it uppercase and between two quotes marks? And what does that two dots does (the ones after the array PricePropName.toLowerCase? And why he passed the variable after the array and in that style?
Sorry for this noob style question but I didn't found this anywhere and I want to understand it)

The code:

```
const pricePropName = "PRICE";

const calculator = (name, price) => {
  return {
    name,
    add(n1, n2) {
      return n1 + n2;
    },
    [pricePropName.toLowerCase()] : price;
  }
}

const calc = calculator('casio', 19.99);

log(calc.name);
log(calc.add(20, 20));
log(calc.price);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why he set the value price and why is it uppercase and between two quotes marks?

He's just declaring a string named `pricePropName` with the value `"PRICE"`. The two quote marks just how you declare a string literal. As to why it's uppercase, there's no particular reason, but probably so he can call the `toLowerCase()` method later. More info on strings: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

> And what does that two dots does

Here, he's declaring a *object literal*. An `object` is a key-value pairing, so whatever is before the `:` is the `key` (or how you access the value), and whatever is after the `:` is the value (what you access).

So if I declare an object like so:

```
const obj = {
    "one": 1
}
```

I have an object, `obj` with 1 key, `"one"` and one associated value, `1`. To access the value, I can either do `obj.one` or `obj["one"]`

Keys in objects are always strings, but you don't necessarily have to wrap them in quotes. I can declare the previous object in the same way like so:

```
const obj = {
    one: 1
}
```

In modern javascript, there's a shorthand, where if you have a variable and add it to an object literal, you don't need to declare a key, if you want to use the name of the variable as the key. So, I can also declare the previous object like so:

```
const one = 1;
const obj = {
    one
}
```

The final thing to understand is the square brackets around `[pricePropName.toLowerCase()]`. Because he's calling a method here (`toLowerCase()`), he normally wouldn't be able to use it as an object key, but by wrapping it in `[]`, it's kind of like saying "do this, and use the result as the key".

The syntax is a bit awkward, so I wouldn't recommend it - it's far clearer to break that out into a variable for readability.

So, finally:

```
const calculator = (name, price) => {
  return {
    name,
    add(n1, n2) {
      return n1 + n2;
    },
    [pricePropName.toLowerCase()] : price;
  }
}
```

is a function called `calculator`, that takes two parameters, `name` and `price` and returns an object literal with 3 key/value properties:

1. `name`, which in this case will refer to `"casio"`
2. `add`, which refers to a function that will add 2 numbers and return the result
3. `price`, which refers to `19.99` in this case

The final object will look like this:

```
{
    "name": "casio",
    "add": function(n1, n2) {
        return n1 + n2
    },
    "price": 19.99
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can basically call/define object property in couple different ways.

Below you have example, how to do this in different ways (all of them doing the same):

```js
const city = "Wroclaw"
const country = "Poland"

const example = {
   name: "Bob",
   ['lastName']: "Smith",
   ['AGE'.toLowerCase()]: 24,
   city,
   country: country
}

console.log(example)
```